# In Behat is there any custom function to pass user credentials to test the API response?

Tags: behat

I am using BehatAPIExtentsion and writing a simple scenario to verify the response code for an endpoint, but I am getting error 406 on executing the scneario. This works properly on POSTMAN tool only fails on behat.

I tried to pass the credentials using the following:

1. Scenario: Verify the login 
   Given the request body is:
   """
   {
       "username": "admin",
       "password": "qa123"
   }
   """
   When I request "/api/v1/user/login" using HTTP "POST"
   Then the response code is "200"
2. Scenario: Verify the login 
   Given the following form parameters are set:
   | name | value |
   | username | admin |
   | password | qa123 |
   When I request "/api/v1/user/login" using HTTP "POST"
   Then the response code is 200

Note : Basic Authentication will not work here so did not use 
Given I am authenticating as "admin" with password "qa123"

Expected : The response code should be 200

Actual : The scenarios dont pass as the response code received is 406. It is not able to login using the credentials in the scenario.
Error : Imbo\BehatApiExtension\Exception\AssertionFailedException: Expected response code 200, got 401

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://behat-api-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes I had checked that documentation.